# Transfer learning from pretrained NN model for non image sequential data

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I have a standard numeric dataset where the predictors are sequential much like an NLP task (not sequenced longitudinally for RNN implementation) with multi-class response to build a classification model. I would build my own NN but I see ResNet has previously been used for similar tasks and I am aware of how to do basic implementation of transfer learning of pretrained models however how would this be impemented for non-image data on a ResNet (or other Image recognition based models). I am assuming a simple layer can be added at the top or can specify the ResNet input dimensions via tensorflow/keras?